# Reading a triangle of numbers into a 2d array of ints in Python

Tags: python, file

I want to read a triangle of integer values from a file into a 2D array of ints using Python. The numbers would look like this:

75

95 64

17 47 82

18 35 87 10

20 04 82 47 65

...

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
arr = []
for i in range(0, 15):
    arr.append([])
    str = f.readline()
    a = str.split(' ')
    for tok in a:
        arr[i].append(int(tok[:2]))

print arr
```

I have a feeling this could be done in a tighter, more Pythonesque way. How would *you* do it?

Comment: You know, when a computer reads a text file such as this, it will not see it as a triangle. Just a very long list of characters. Sure it will see the white space, such as `space` and `new line`. You could just use a `read integer` function (note you will need to find the proper function) and store it into a simple array. Though you may be after storing them in a 2D array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
arr = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in open('input.txt')]
```

Comment: variation on the theme: `arr = [map(int, line.split()) for line in fileinput.input()]`

Answer (score 0):

The ways I can think of would be...

```
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        line_array = file.read().splitlines()
        cell_array = []
        for line in line_array:
            cell_array.append(line.split())
        print(cell_array)
```

A little compression :

```
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        line_array = file.read().splitlines()
        cell_array = [line.split() for line in line_array]
        print(cell_array)
```

**Even more compression !**

```
    print([[item for item in line.split()] for line in open(path)])
```